# Alternative WHOIS client for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, sysinternals, whois

The de-facto whois client is Whois 1.20 From SysInternals, but it currently tries to contact moniker.com each time you attempt a whois, and now it is running into an endless loop situation.

Comment: Did you try specifying the whois server?  (Parameter for the whois command).  Try uninstalling it and reinstalling to see if you can do this.  Alternative:  whois on the web (domaintools.com)

Comment: Ask this over here>>>>>>>>>https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Whois can be done from the Windows command prompt, extract the contents of the sysinternals whois zip to the C:\Windows system32 folder.

From the Windows command prompt, simply type the following

> whois -v example.com

Because this is a text-based service, there will be something of a “wall of text” output from your whois program, but in that listing you will see all the same information as you would see from a web-based search: who owns the domain, when it was registered and who with, when it is due for renewal, who the domain is registered to and all sorts of other information about that domain.

To make the Whois output easier to read, redirect its output to a text file that you can then scroll through using a common text editor such as Notepad or Notepad++. Here’s how to write the Whois output to a text file.

From the command prompt, simply type the following (replacing example.com with the domain you’d like to query, then look for the text file on your desktop.

> whois -v example.com > example.txt

[Source](https://www.techjunkie.com/whois-windows-command-prompt/)

Comment: Windows 10 : "'whois' is not recognized as an internal or external command".

Comment: Forgot, first you have to extract the sysinternals whois ZIP file to c:\windows\system32